# VPS is slow despite low memory and cpu usages

Tags: performance, vps

recently the website hosted on VPS becomes very hard to reach at times, and I am trying to figure out why. I noticed the following things:

- CPU and memory usages are very low (always <15% if we sum everything up but usually even less than that);
- website is extremely slow to load but whenever I connect to the VPS through SSH it works very smoothly;
- I checked the activity in phpMyAdmin, whenever those slowdowns happen the statistics page takes a lot of time to refresh (up to 20-30 seconds while it's set to 5 seconds - number of queries per second doesn't seem to increase though);
- it doesn't seem to depend on the number of people online.

Considering those observations, what should I try to check/debug in order to find a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by many different issues. For whatever reason it would appear that your process are waiting on something that takes some time to complete. It is doubtful that this is IO as you'd see higher load averages. The question is what. Here are a couple of things to try if the VPS is linux:

- iostat from the sysstat package will diagnose if it is a IO issue
- Run strace -fp  of process while you perform a slow request. Ctrl-c strace when done. Watch the system calls during the slow request. Likely it will stop on one and then continue. strace dumps tons of information so you may want to use the -o. It may also dump lots of information from other connections if they are concurrent and handled by the same process in another thread or the like.
- Increase logging in the application/database and try to narrow down the issue

My guess would be that you're performing reverse look ups on the source of connections either in your code or in logging. If this is done synchronously each connection is going to wait for the response from the DNS server and cripple your response time.

The other possibility is that you are using mysql and myisam for it's storage type with a lot of concurrent writes. Myisam does table level locking (or at least it used to). The entire table will be locked for writing until the write is finished with it's query/write. Each connection will have to wait in turn to write to the database.